# Finding the vertices of a given polytope

Tags: c, computational-geometry, linear-programming, polyhedra

I'm looking for a C library that can return the vertices of a polytope.

Comment: [Vertex enumeration problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these tools:

- lrs (http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/C/lrs.html)
- polymake (https://polymake.org/doku.php)
- cdd (https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/)